# Jupyter notebook No module named 'torch' even if I have installed torch

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I was working with jupyter notebook, using `!pip list` I'm sure I have selected the correct environment, yet jupyter notebook still reports `No module named 'torch'`.

I have also tried `import torch` in command line and it worked well. How to fix this problem?
[image]

Comment: are you running this notebook in a conda environment?

Comment: yes, it's a conda environment

Comment: what's the output from `conda list -n {environment name}`

Comment: torch is included in the output after running the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

`pip install jupyter` in terminal and restart jupyter notebook will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in conda environment then,

```
conda create -n {environment name}

conda activate env_pytorch

pip install torchvision
```

use this you can install torch